# Split messages from one inbox to another 2 inboxes based on content

Tags: email, postfix, smtp, procmail

is there a way via Postfix and or procmail for example or another software to forward e-mails from one inbox to another 2 inboxes where each message goes either to one inbox or the other based on content. Sometimes the message is multipart and the keyword is within the first part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Procmail itself doesn't have any facility for looping over messages you have already received, but the companion `formail` utility to loop over messages in an mbox file; or, of course, if you are using a mailbox format like Maildir, you can simply loop over the files which contain those messages.

```
for file in ~/Maildir/cur/deadbeefdecafbadc001b00c ~/Maildir/cur/badc0415106644511745; do
    procmail -m testing.rc <"$file";
done
```

where `testing.rc` might contain something like

```
:0
* ^Subject: (foo|bar)
! elsewhere@example.net

:0
! fallback@example.org
```

to send the matching messages to the first address and the others to the second. (Probably test with a rule which doesn't send anything anywhere!)

For manipulating an mbox file, the invocation would look something like

```
formail -s procmail -m testing.rc <messages.mbox
```

To look inside the first MIME part, you basically need to figure out how to extract that part into something Procmail can read. If the content could be base64, you need a base64 decoder, and some pretty complex logic to isolate the message part. Perhaps at that point, use a third-party tool with better support for examining the innards of modern MIME messages? Here is a simple Python tool.

```
from email import message_from_binary_file
from email.policy import default
import sys

for filename in sys.argv[1:]:
    with open(filename, "rb") as msg:
        message = message_from_binary_file(msg, policy=default)
    if "fnord" in message.get_body(preferencelist=('plain', 'html')).get_content():
        print(f"{filename}: there")
    else:
        print(f"{filename}: not there")
```

This simply prints "there" or "not there" depending on whether the search term was found. You could obviously extend this to move or copy the input file to another directory, or send the message to a different address, or do something else within the Python script itself; or run it from a Bash script and respond to its output.

But to return to Procmail, if all you need is searching of a simple text/plain part, and can live with it unnecessarily searching other parts than the first one, maybe it's enough to say

```
:0B
* (\<fnord\>)
! found@xample.net
```

(which demonstrates word boundaries around the search phrase, unlike my Python example). This is pretty brittle still, because even a quoted-printable message could contain

```
Content-type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-transfer-encoding: quoted-printable

Annoyingly, QP lets you insert a newline in the midd=
le of a word, so you could end up not finding this f=
nord occurrence.
```

which the simple Python tool above copes with magnificently.

Comment: I have done a fair amount of bespoke MIME parsing in Procmail, but it's never fun and never properly reusable, so I'd rather not do it again. That's not to say it can't be done. If you understand MIME, find the boundary, peek inside, don't go beyond the next boundary. Or use a tool like `ripmime` to tear the message apart and examine the disk files it produced.

Comment: What about if I just implement one simple perl script doing the job directly on the file system ?

Comment: That would work fine just as well; it's not clear from your question whether you want to resend the messages off the system or just copy them within the local filesystem. The main burden remains figuring out how to navigate the MIME structure and decode anything which is encoded.

Comment: Basilcy what I want is to divide messages in two inboex nased on a relativly complex Rule which can be determined by the First Content in a Multipart message. So i need to evaluate and parse the first Boundary in order to decide in which inbox should the message fall.

Comment: To be honest I am now even more tempted to use Perl :) instead of ProcMail. Seems to me it will be easier to parse the first body part and decide where it should go.

Comment: It's been a long time since I used Perl, but godspeed. The Python `email` library encapsulates many of the complications nicely; the `get_body()` shortcut to find the first inline body part according to a preference list is particularly useful for many real-world scenarios.

Comment: I remember Ricardo Signes had many useful email libraries; https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Filter seems pretty close to what you seem to be asking for.